# Is there a rule regarding the placement of "please" in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, politeness

Both written or spoken?

For example:

- Please have a seat.
- Have a seat please.

And how would the use of commas change the meaning or tone of the request?
Are there other options that I've excluded?

Comment: "Have *please* a seat."; "Have a *please* seat."; "*Pl*have *ea*a *se*seat."

Comment: In theory it's either "Please have a seat" or "Have a seat, please", but the comma in the second (indicating a brief pause) is probably optional.  The only major difference in tone would be from emphasizing "please", making the request seem more like an order (especially in the second case).

Comment: a seat, please have

Comment: Note, first of all, that _please_ is used **only** in invitations, questions, requests, and orders. It's never used in statements: **He please sat down.* Second, it is sometimes an adverb, in formulas like _Will/Would you please,_ and sometimes a verb in formulas like _if you please, as you please, it pleases me, I'm pleased to say,_ etc. In the adverb formulas, it can appear at the beginning, after the subject, or at the end of the formula, set off by comma intonation at the beginning or end.

Comment: @John Lawler I'm not happy with the classification as adverb. I suppose traditionally it was classed as a sentential adverb, but it never did any verb-modifying. In 'Hey, have a seat', 'Hey' would usually have been classed as an interjection. I'm still convinced that these pragmatic markers, meta to the matrix sentence, tacked on to convey politeness or to grab attention etc, are better considered as separate entities.

Comment: Call it something else, then. How about interjection? It doesn't matter; what does matter is that it appears to niche the way an adverb does.